# Why are pipe operations not working in my shell?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, stdin, dup2

I am trying to make shell.

This is my struct for storing command:

```c
struct command {
    char *comm;
    char *args[MAX_NO_ARGS+2];
    int no_args;
    int order;
};
```

In these function I trim the command based on argument and pipe operators:

```c
char *mytrim(char *s);
int get_commands(char *line, struct command mycommands[]);
void print_command(struct command mycommands[], int no_commands);
```

[image]

These are my two function for execute command and pipe handling:

```
void execute_commands(struct command mycommands[], int no_commands);
int execute_command(char *command, int argc, char *args[], int fd_in, int fd_out);
```

When I call `execute_commands()` for pipe handling and `execute_command()` for executing instead of printing.
I got stuck at infinite reading

[image]

Also when I tried (`ifconfig | grep "dropped"`) command, it's printing whole `ifconfig` detail and then infinite reading.

```c
void execute_commands(struct command mycommands[], int no_commands)
{
    if (no_commands == 1) {
        execute_command(mycommands[0].comm, mycommands[0].no_args, mycommands[0].args, -1, -1);
    } else {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int fd[no_commands-1][2];
        for (i = 0; i < no_commands; i++) {
            pipe(fd[i]);

        }
        for (i = 0; i < no_commands; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                execute_command(mycommands[i].comm, mycommands[i].no_args, mycommands[i].args, -1, fd[i][1]);
            } else if (i == no_commands -1 ) {
                execute_command(mycommands[i].comm, mycommands[i].no_args, mycommands[i].args, fd[i-1][0], -1);
            } else {
                execute_command(mycommands[i].comm, mycommands[i].no_args, mycommands[i].args, fd[i-1][0], fd[i][1]);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < no_commands-1; i++) {
            close(fd[i][0]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int execute_command(char *command, int argc, char *args[], int fd_in, int fd_out)
{
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (fd_in) {
            close(fd_in);
            dup2(fd_in, STDIN_FILENO);
            execvp(command, args);
        }
        if (fd_out) {
            close(fd_out);
            dup2(fd_out, STDOUT_FILENO);
            execvp(command, args);
        }
        if (fd_in == fd_out == -1) {
            execvp(command, args);
        }
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your `execute_command`, (1) what happens when you have both `fd_in` and `fd_out`? (2) when do `if (fd_in)` or `if (fd_out)` fail?

Comment: (1) `fd_in` and `fd_out` work when we have more than 2 commands let suppose we have 3 commands seperated by pipe so it will create two pipes, i didn't observe it yet because second command is not getting  anything from stdin or continuos reading

Comment: "(1) fd_in and fd_out work". How exactly do they both work in the same call? Write down all statements that get executed in this case. You have not answered (2) yet :)

Comment: I'm passing pipe array `fd` to function `execute_command` in case of `cat a.txt | grep "a"` it will create a pipe, in `execute_command` ,for `cat a.txt` it will fork a child and based on `fd_in` and `fd_out` values which is `-1` because no initial input is required and `fd[i][1]`  it will assign file pointer to `stdout` using `dup2()` , now the output of `cat` is in stdout but in second command `grep` based on  `fd_in` and `fd_out` value will be `fd[i][0]` and `-1` now i used `dup2()` for replacing read end of pipe to `stdin` .

Comment: my question is why the result of first command is printing instead of going in `stdout` and why second command not getting anything from `stdin`?

Comment: Let me ask directly. If `fd_in` is -1, what does `if (fd_in)` do? Is what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237405/discussion-between-talha-hassan-and-n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m).

Comment: Don't post images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Hint: may be do some diagnostic printouts from `execute_command()` to see which calls to `execvp()` are executed in different cases...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing fds in the wrong order. You write:

```
    close(fd_in);
    dup2(fd_in, STDIN_FILENO);
```

but you need to dup first with:

```
    dup2(fd_in, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd_in);
```

Also, the logic looks suspect.  Rather than:

```
 if (fd_out) {
```

you probably want

```
if (fd_out != 1) {
```

checking `if (fd_in == fd_out == -1)` almost certainly does not do what you think it does.  (By that, I mean you probably think that it is checking `(fd_in == -1 && fd_out == -1)`, but it is not).  You need to check the value returned from `pipe` rather than the values of the file descriptors.

Also, it is incorrect to have `exec` in multiple places.  The way your code is currently structured, assuming no errors, `fd_in` will always be non-zero and your code will `exec` after it dups `fd_in`.  It will never even check `fd_out` and certainly it will never dup it to `stdout`.  You should delete the `exec`s in the if clauses and only call `exec` once.  The only code you should ever write after an `exec` is `perror("exec"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: Still the same issue `grep`  commamd still getting something from `stdin` may be i am not closing read end of pipes perfectly

Comment: @Talhahassan You are never dup'ing stdout.  In your code, you `exec` right after you dup stdin, and there's no way you get to the next bit of code.  You should only exec once, and you need to do it after both dups.

Answer (score 0):

You should also close fd_in and fd_out in parent process